# Duplicating dated code: getting innerHTML error

Tags: javascript, jsdom

Trying to complete a basic program from a JS course to display an array of user info, and I get an error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined'...

I'm matching the course environment (Node v6.17.1, npm v3.10.10.). There are two issues I see, not sure if related:

(1) When duplicating instructor's code, the editor won't let me declare 'global.document' (see full line of code below)

(2) The error message points to index.test.js, with the following information:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
      at Object.done (C:/Users/Chris/js-dev-env/src/index.test.js:16:17)
      at node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom.js:320:18
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:9)
```

Here is the code from index.js that I tried to type, but editor won't let me declare global.document property (maybe this is older syntax?)

```
  global.document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = usersBody;
```

...

```
describe('index.html', () => {
  it('should have h1 that displays Users', (done) => {
    const index = fs.readFileSync('./src/index.html', "utf-8");
    jsdom.env(index, function(err, window) {
      const h1 = window.document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
      expect(h1.innerHTML).to.equal("users");
      done();
      window.close();
    });
 });
})
```

Expecting 3 rows of user info to be displayed (fName, lName, email). Can't get past the .innerHTML error.

Comment: Hi Cris! Please share with us your html. Look like your problem is that user html tag does not exist.

Comment: Where are you exactly using `global.document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = usersBody;` ?
It seems that you are using _node-jsdom_. You will only have `document` available once you have executed `jsdom.env`.

Comment: Hi @Nico, here is the code in my index.html file:                     
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Users</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="users">

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @mgarcia, was this perhaps not the case with older versions?  (I ask because I'm copying the instructor's code letter for letter.) I am importing jsdom in my index.test.js file (as instructed): The top 3 lines of code import the following:                                                                                        
    import {expect} from 'chai';
    import jsdom from 'jsdom';
    import fs from 'fs';

Comment: Please, complete your question with all the necessary code so that we can help you better (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the complete code for `index.test.js` and the `bundle.js` file that is loaded with your `index.html`. Also, `package.json` would be helpful.

Comment: @mgarcia, I am thrilled to share that I fixed the issue! In my index.test.js, I had a check in my code that mistakenly looked for 'users' (with a lower case u) instead of 'Users'. I fixed that and was able to reproduce the desired outcome in the program. Here was the line of code in question that I fixed: expect(h1.innerHTML).to.equal("Users"); Thank you for your time and patience. Cheers~